# What is shadowing?

Tags: asp.net

what is shadowing in .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/18405

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Shadowing-using-Shadows-in-Visual-Basic-NET-2005/

Answer (score 7):

Shadowing in general:

> In computer programming, variable
>   **shadowing** occurs when a variable
>   declared within a certain scope
>   (decision block, method, or inner
>   class) has the same name as a variable
>   declared in an outer scope. This outer
>   variable is said to be shadowed. This
>   can lead to confusion, as it may be
>   unclear which variable subsequent uses
>   of the shadowed variable name refer
>   to.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 0):

The terminology specific more into .Net. 
Its techniuqe of **replacing a member of a base class with a new member from the derived class**. It differs from overriding in that base class's shadowed member is no longer available from the derived class.